# How to make fetch dynamic link JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make `fetch('/fetchDataAll')`dynamic. Depending which button is clicked. Anyone to help?

**JavaScript**

```
class DbApi {
    constructor() {

    }
    async getDbData() {
        const dataResponse = await fetch('/fetchDataAll')

        const dataJson = await dataResponse.json()

        return dataJson

    }
}


// the object that maps the data-fetcher attributes to their equivalent functions
const fetcherObject = {
    all: fetchAll,
    rookies: fetchRookies,
    ufra: fetchUrfa

};

const bestBtn = document.querySelector('.jsBestBtnList')

bestBtn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    let target = e.target;
    let fetchFn = fetcherObject[target.dataset.fetcher];
    if (fetchFn) { 
        fetchFn();

    }

});

let show = document.querySelector('#show')

const dbApi = new DbApi

function fetchAll(){
  dbApi.getDbData()
    .then(data => {
        show.innerHTML = "";
        let players = data.result; // Get the results

        show.innerHTML  = players.map(player => {

            let colorToChange = "";
            let plusMinusSign = "";
            let colorWhite = "#FFFFFF";


            if (player.scoreChange >= 0) {
                colorToChange = "#66FF13";
                plusMinusSign = "+";
            }
            else {
                colorToChange = "#D0021B";
                plusMinusSign = "";
            }

            return `<p style='color:${colorWhite}'>${player.playerName}</p>
            <p style='color:${colorWhite}'>${player.teamName}</p>
            <h3 style='color:${colorToChange}'>${plusMinusSign} ${player.scoreChange} %</h3>`
        }).join('')

    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="jsBestNtnList">
    <button class="fetcher-btn" data-fetcher="all">Fetch all</button>
    <button class="fetcher-btn" data-fetcher="ufra">Fetch ufra</button>
    <button class="fetcher-btn" data-fetcher="rookies">Fetch rookies</button>
</div>
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: I need to make it dynamic `fetch('/fetchDataAll')` depending which button is clicked

Comment: Sure, but what does that mean? Do you what the argumen of `fetch` to change based on the content of given button?

Comment: yes ,  `fetch(`${link}`)` meaning that the link will change depending on the request

Comment: What is `.jsBestBtnList`, you don't have it in your html? Is it wrapper around those `fetcher-btn`'s?

Comment: You can always pass a parameter to your `getDbData` function and use that as your fetch call argument

Comment: @MatusDubrava yes, to implement event delegation

Comment: @ChiragRavindra I am not sure how to pass a parameter in this case

Comment: What exact strings should be passed to that function?

Comment: just the `response` from database in Json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add and modify your code like this (rest stays unchanged).

```js
// new piece of code
// urls for given buttons (change it to your needs)
const urls = {
  all: '/url1',
  rookies: '/url2',
  ufra: /'url3'
};

async getDbData(url) {                   // pass the argument here
  const dataResponse = await fetch(url)  // and here
  const dataJson = await dataResponse.json()
  return dataJson
}

const bestBtn = document.querySelector('.jsBestBtnList')

bestBtn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    let target = e.target;
    let fetchFn = fetcherObject[target.dataset.fetcher];
    
    // fetch url the same way you are fetching the function
    let arg = urls[target.dataset.fetcher];
    if (fetchFn) {
        fetchFn(arg); // pass the argument here
    }
});

function fetchAll(url){ // pass it here 
  dbApi.getDbData(url)  // here as well
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: it looks pretty good . I will try to implement it and let you now! Thank you Matus!

Comment: This is perfect solution. It works just as I wanted! I really appreciate it Matus!

Answer (score 0):

The least intrusive way of handling this (there are probably better ways which would need major restructuring of your code) would be to define three functions for each of fetch items defined in the `fetcherObject`. And make `getDbData` accept  a `path` parameter which would be a different URL based on which would be passed by the three different functions.

```js
class DbApi {
  constructor() {

  }
  async getDbData(path) {
    const dataResponse = await fetch(path)

    const dataJson = await dataResponse.json()

    return dataJson

  }
}


// the object that maps the data-fetcher attributes to their equivalent functions
const fetcherObject = {
  all: fetchAll,
  rookies: fetchRookies,
  ufra: fetchUrfa
};

const bestBtn = document.querySelector('.jsBestBtnList')

bestBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  let target = e.target;
  let fetchFn = fetcherObject[target.dataset.fetcher];
  if (fetchFn) {
    fetchFn();

  }

});
const dbApi = new DbApi


// Functions which call getDbData with different params based on button clicked
function fetchAll() {
  dbApi.getDbData('/fetchDataAll')
    .then(data => {
      // .. Rest of code

    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
function fetchUrfa() {
  dbApi.getDbData('/fetchDataUfra')
    .then(data => {
      // .. Rest of code

    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}

function fetchRookies() {
  dbApi.getDbData('/fetchDataRookies')
    .then(data => {
      // .. Rest of code

    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="jsBestNtnList">
  <button class="fetcher-btn" data-fetcher="all">Fetch all</button>
  <button class="fetcher-btn" data-fetcher="ufra">Fetch ufra</button>
  <button class="fetcher-btn" data-fetcher="rookies">Fetch rookies</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It's hard to recommend a way to refactor it (and probably also the wrong site to do it on) without understanding what those three buttons and APIs do. My recommendation would be to keep things DRY (Don't repeat yourself) and KISS (Keep it simple, silly). If you need help structuring code, I would recommend asking the guys over at [CodeReview StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a url parameter to getDbData, something like this:

```
class DbApi {
    constructor() {
    }

    async getDbData(url) {
        const dataResponse = await fetch(url)
        const dataJson = await dataResponse.json()
        return dataJson
    }
}

const bestBtn = document.querySelector('.jsBestBtnList')

bestBtn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    let target = e.target;
    let url = target.dataset.url;
    if (url) { 
        fetchUrl(url);
    }
});

let show = document.querySelector('#show')

const dbApi = new DbApi

function fetchUrl(url){
  dbApi.getDbData(url)
    .then(data => {
        show.innerHTML = "";
        let players = data.result; // Get the results

        show.innerHTML  = players.map(player => {

            let colorToChange = "";
            let plusMinusSign = "";
            let colorWhite = "#FFFFFF";


            if (player.scoreChange >= 0) {
                colorToChange = "#66FF13";
                plusMinusSign = "+";
            }
            else {
                colorToChange = "#D0021B";
                plusMinusSign = "";
            }

            return `<p style='color:${colorWhite}'>${player.playerName}</p>
            <p style='color:${colorWhite}'>${player.teamName}</p>
            <h3 style='color:${colorToChange}'>${plusMinusSign} ${player.scoreChange} %</h3>`
        }).join('')

    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}


<button class="fetcher-btn" data-url="/fetchDataAll">Fetch all</button>
<button class="fetcher-btn" data-url="/fetchDataUfra">Fetch ufra</button>
<button class="fetcher-btn" data-url="/fetchDataRookies">Fetch rookies</button>
```

Comment: Thank you Mihai ! I will try to implement it !